# Fullscreen API for Chrome on iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, html5-fullscreen

I am creating a widget that I would like to go fullscreen once a button is clicked. I have implemented the fullscreen API and it works like a charm on all browsers. However, I am creating this widget to work as a interactive kiosk on iPads only. I have the freedom to use whatever browser that works best, but I can not get the fullscreen functionality to work on my iPad. Have tried multiple different options but to no suffice... I have the following code that works on normal desktop browsers:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var fullscreenButton = document.getElementById('fullscreenButton');

fullscreenButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(element.requestFullscreen){
        element.requestFullscreen();
    }else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen){
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen){
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }else if(element.msRequestFullscreen){
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else{
        element.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }
});
```

Is there any way possible for me to create an application (which is basically a slideshow) to enter fullscreen on iPads, in any way possible? Thanks in advance for all tips/help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Safari for IOS does not support Full screen: http://caniuse.com/#search=full%20screen

As far as I know Chrome for IOS is based on Safari so, if Safari doesn't support Full screen, Chrome will not support it.

Check this link for more details (they suggest some solutions, but not very good): https://forum.playcanvas.com/t/struggling-to-run-in-full-screen-mode-ios-chrome/2008